# Can anyone tell me why on one of my pages, the footer appears twice?

Tags: ajax, jquery

http://adamshort.site50.net/#cv

On my portolio site I have used ajax to animate content load, but am wondering how I can make the transitions smoother as each page differes in length, and also why does the footer appear twice on the linked page above? This is the tutorial I followed:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/

Comment: [Should I paste a link to my project?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126000/215013). Can you edit your post with the offending code here?

Comment: It appears you have included your ``#foot`` div in ``cv.html``. Since you are also loading the content in via ajax, it is displaying twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using a master page and have called the footer from both the master and child.

[image]